# How to display two array's values left and right in table view like chat Dialog Window

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having two array's, one is senderArray and other is recieverArray. In both arrays i have Messages data in JSON format.

Now i want to display all data in left(recieverArray) and right(senderArray) of table view.

Something like this -
 [image]

Please suggest me how could i do it.

Comment: Down votes are accepted. please understand, i want to display in customise window like chat dialog

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984672/create-a-simple-chat-view-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Use tableView's delegate methods.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Set the corresponding array data in cell.

Comment: I know it but how the data will be set left and right side like chat window

Answer (score 0):

NSARRAY, it is possible through TableView CustomCell. In UITableView CustomCell take two labels, set the first label to the right Side and the other label to the left side. Display your JSON parsing data array into this label.

Comment: i have 100 messages in both arrays i have to show all messages in left and right

Comment: @NSArray it is Possible why Not in `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and Set `NumberOf Rows in UITableView` is Your array Count and Set Section is equal to 1.

Comment: @NSArray Then use Custum Libraray [link]
(https://github.com/samsoffes/ssmessagesviewcontroller) Hope it Helps You.